# Failed to build docker container with error related to APT

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, github-actions

Trying to build the following simple Dockerfile on GitHub Action using public runner "ubuntu-latest".

```
FROM jupyter/tensorflow-notebook:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update
```

It failed with following error:

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

not sure why this happened since it worked in local computer.

Is this any sort of Linux specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

as a Troubleshoot, you can divide the commands in specific "RUN".

So, you can check on which step the error is occurring.

Comment: Hi @r31sr4r , i have divided them into "RUN" and now updated the description. it failed on apt-get

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I had a Dockerfile which had the below (among other things) :

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get -y upgrade 
RUN apt-get -y update
```

The file worked the first time I used it to build an image but the second time I got the same error as you. I remembered that Docker caches everything installed from the file and will only re-process parts of the file which have changed since the last time it was used. So I just swapped the order around to this (put ubuntu on bottom and python on top):

```
FROM python:3.8      
FROM ubuntu
             
RUN apt-get -y upgrade 
RUN apt-get -y update
```

re-ran docker build on the file and it worked. Really annoying hack that worked for me. Hope it works for someone else!